# What does near-cut (threshold) graph say about original complete weighted graph?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, network

### ORIGINAL post, preamble

Start from a complete graph with weighted edges (e.g. in $[0,1]$ interval). Continuously increasing threshold $t$ from $0$ to $1$ drop edges with weights less than $t$. Finally stop right before the graph would become disconnected. See animation. Consider remaining connected graph - call it "**threshold graph**". **What does its properties/structure say about the original complete graph?** It is probably related to [graph theory edge cut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_(graph_theory)) and [max-flow min-cut theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max-flow_min-cut_theorem). But those are based on the minimal set of edges to disconnect a graph. What I really would like to understand in my case **if any properties of the "**threshold graph**" say something mathematically interesting about the original complete graph**. I especially interested in communities and clusters, but anything else interesting too.

Such question often appears in problems with a complete set of relationships in a finite set - like a group of people, stocks in a portfolio, etc. *Any thoughts and help are highly appriciated!*

[image]

This basically similar to "percolation" or "watershed" problems. Here is very simplistic formulation of it.

### UPDATE: simple clean problem

1. N interacting agents - anyone with everyone - complete graph
2. Interactions varies in strength - reflected in edge weights
3. Drop all edges weaker than a particular weight - "threshold" - and replace the edges you kept with same uniform weight
4. This is a simple skeleton graph in which graph communities cam be studied
5. The BIG question is - "how to choose cut-off threshold" ?
6. Threshold type 1:

   - agents represented by time series of data (say stock price)
   - edge weights are Pearson correlation coefficient between time series
   - cut-off threshold is typical "strong" Pearson value - say 0.75 or similar
   - such cut-off is typical but pretty vague and subjective - it is not dictated by data
7. Threshold type 2:

   - agents represented by time series of data (say stock price)
   - edge weights are Pearson correlation coefficient between time series
   - cut-off threshold is "the last MAX edge we drop while graph is still connected"
   - such cut-off is naturally arises from data
   - i guess this is important for problems where skeleton threshold graph must still connect all agents

**THE QUESTION: in what cases (7) should be chosen over (6) and what metrics we can drive from it, especially towards communities/structure? What mathematical reasoning can give preference to (7) over (6)?**

For practical example please see:

https://blog.wolfram.com/2012/06/01/graph-theory-and-finance-in-mathematica

Comment: I don't have any answers, but looking into random weight minimum spanning trees might yield some insights. One, the threshold graph might not be a tree, and two, they are more interested in the direct problem (weight the edges randomly, what is the expected structure of the MWST) rather than your "inverse" problem (given threshold graph, infer information about the original weights). Interesting note: the MWST has small expected diameter ($\Theta(n^{1/3})$). You might also look at critical graphs. Here's a paper that discusses both: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/rsa.20241

Comment: Could you perhaps provide some intuition about what might be "mathematically interesting" about the original graph? Since it's already know to be a complete graph, I have to assume you're not thinking of graph structure. So it must be something related to the edge weights, but I'm having trouble figuring out what might be considered interesting there.

Comment: @mhum -- thank you for your interest! I updated the post with cleaner formulation.

Comment: @BenjaminBaily  thank you for your references - very insightful. Please take a look at some further thoughts I added in my post.

Comment: Thanks for adding the further detail. I have no specific insights here but would advise perhaps identifying why connectivity is important in this context (e.g.: what particular meaning is there associated with that last connected graph?)